# REGEXP CONTAINS from splitted strings

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have this data:

[image: data]

I want to categorize the data, if in each row there's a country that has no 'all' label in it, marked as 1.

Else, marked as 0.

Based on this rule, the first row marked as 0 and the second row marked as 1 (it has a country without 'all' label in it

And we have to examine every single value (after being splitted) because we are looking for a value (country) that has no 'all' in it.

I tried this query:

```
SELECT 
    MAX(CASE WHEN NOT REGEXP_CONTAINS(
    (SELECT * EXCEPT(c) REPLACE(c AS country) FROM test_table, UNNEST(SPLIT(country)) c), r'all'
    ) THEN 1
    ELSE 0 END) AS is_not_all
FROM test_table
```

turns out it shows error : *scalar subquery cannot have more than one column unless using select as struct to build struct*

Is there anyway to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . You can just use `like`:

```
select t.*,
       (select countif(trim(country) not like 'all %')
        from unnest(split(country, ',')) c
       ) > 0
from t;
```

Or without the aggregation:

```
select t.*,
       exists (select 1
               from unnest(split(country, ',')) c
               where country not like 'all %'
              ) 
from t;
```

Comment: The without aggregation works for me with some modification:
    exists (select 1
               from unnest(split(country, ',')) c
               where c not like 'all%'
              ) 

notice the 'c' after where instead of 'country'